# framework7 demo login success,then how to router a list page

Tags: html-framework-7

1. In index.html with login form

   ... login screen content ...
2. When logged in successfully, how can I route another page and close (or hide) the current login page?

   ```
      mainView.router.load('default.html');
   ```

This script doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

`mainView.router.loadPage('default.html')`

or this:

 `mainView.router.load({url:'default.html'});`

taken from the docs: http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/router-api.html#.VTPFbiFViko

Answer (score 0):

If You are usong Login Modal You have to close Login Modal before the **LoadPage**

```
mainView.router.loadPage('default.html')
if(response=='Success')
{
  myApp.closeModal();
  localStorage.loggedIn = 'true';
  mainView.router.loadPage('home.html')
}
```